# Add title for options in Quasar select

Tags: javascript, select, quasar

[image]
Hello guys! I need to make a title for options in q-select, but I didn't find anything like that in the Quasar documentation. If anyone has experience with Quasar please let me know, thanks.

P.S. Picture for example

Answer (score 1):

It's easy use `before-options` slot

```
<q-select
        filled
        v-model="model"
        :options="options"
        label="Options"
      >
        <template v-slot:before-options>
          <q-item>
            <q-item-section class="text-italic text-grey">
              No options slot
            </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
        </template>
      </q-select>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/jOxZqyz

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit later, but hope this works for others.

First: the q-select only works with a main array, so you will need to split the work:

NOTE: This example is using Vee-validate 4 and yup. I highly recommend both.

1. Create the template with the example

```html
<ValidateField name="state" v-slot="{ field, value, errors }">
          <q-select
            v-bind="field"
            :model-value="value"
            :options="countries"
            :option-value="'abbreviation'"
            :option-label="'name'"
            :label="stateLabel"
            :error-message="errors[0]"
            :error="errors.length > 0"
            :disabled="disabled"
            emit-value
            map-options>
            <template v-slot:option="scope">
              <q-list>
                <q-item-label v-if="scope.opt.disabled" header>{{ scope.opt.name }}</q-item-label>
                <q-item
                  v-if="!scope.opt.disabled"
                  :key="scope.opt.abbreviation"
                  clickable
                  v-ripple
                  v-close-popup
                  v-bind="scope.itemProps">
                  <q-item-section>
                    <q-item-label class="q-ml-md" >{{scope.opt.name}}</q-item-label>
                  </q-item-section>
                </q-item>
              </q-list>
            </template>
          </q-select>
        </ValidateField>
```

2. Handle the data. This is an example

```js
const initialValue = [];
    actions = rawActions.reduce((accumulator, country) => {
      const { abbreviation, name, states } = country;
      states.unshift({
        abbreviation,
        name,
        disabled: true,
      });
      return accumulator.concat(states);
    }, initialValue);
```